# Call Methode from Event in XAML

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Is it possible to have a UserControl with an Event (Event GoUp) that calls a Methode in an second Usercontrol (Sub Upgoing), and all this in WPF/XAML?

```
<controls:Joystick/>  <!--with Event GoUp-->
<controls:TV/>        <!--Sub Upgoing that should be called when Event GoUp is fired-->
```

I know how to solve this in Code Behind or ViewModel, but it is possible in XAML??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no. You cannot call methods in pure XAML.

You may *hook up* event handlers in XAML, but you'll still need to implement the event handler programmatically.

Also, if `Joystick` and `TV` are siblings in the element tree, an event raised from one of them won't bubble up or tunnel down to the other. A routed event either travels up or down, not sideways.

Comment: What a pity! An other approach: Is it possible to refer to another UI-Element in XAML. Like this: `<controls:TV Joystick="{Binding ElementName=TVsName, Mode=OneTime}"/>`?

Comment: @hilrol: Yes, but only if the elements are in the same XAML [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: And how to do that? Because this code doesn't work out for me: `<controls:Joystick x:Name="Stick"/> <controls:TV Joystick="{Binding ElementName=Stick, Mode=OneTime}"/>` With DependencyProperty Joystick.

Comment: @hilrol: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.